# C language Pointer related questions

Tags: c, pointers

Hi i'm studying pointers now.
But while studying, I have a question and I want to ask

```
#include<stdio.h>

void store1(char **p){
    char *tmp = "hello";
    *p = tmp;
    return;
}

void store2(char *p){
    char *tmp = "hello";
    p = tmp;
    return;
}

int main(){
    char *p;
    //store1(&p, num);
    store2(p);
    printf("%s\n", p);
}
```

This is my questions
Why does store1 function not have a segment fault and store2 function has a segment fault?

Why should we pass a variable of type char** as an argument to store a string?

If the char* type is passed as an argument, the char* tmp variable and the type match, so shouldn't it be stored in p?

Please let me know, smart brothers

Comment: Because `p = tmp` can never result in a segfault, you're simply assigning a pointer. And `*p = tmp;` segfaults because `p` is an invalid pointer (it points nowhere).

Comment: Don't name your parameters the same as the arguments and it will be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`store2(p)` does not change `p`, so the value of `p` in main remains uninitialized.  The subsequent `printf("%s\n", p);` thus invokes undefined behavior.  (Indeed, I am not a language lawyer, but I'm pretty sure invoking `store2(p)` when p is not initialized invokes UB.) In `store1`, you pass the address of `p`, and the call to `store1` is able to modify the value of `p` in main so that it now points to a string literal and the subsequent `printf` is valid.

Here, I've re-written your code and changed some variable names to ease the discussion below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void store1(char **a){ *a = "hello"; return; }
void store2(char  *b){  b = "hello"; return; }
int
main(void)
{
    char *p = NULL;   
    store2(p);  /* After store2 returns, p is still NULL */
    store1(&p); /* store1 assigns a value to p */
    printf("%s\n", p);
}
```

In the above, `b` is assigned the value NULL when `store2` is called, but that value is never used.  `b` is effectively a local variable that is assigned the address of the string literal "hello", and that variable is discarded when `store2` returns.  However, `a` is assigned the address of `p`, and the assignment `*a = "hello"` sets `p` to the address of the string literal "hello".

Answer (score 0):

Look here. I inlined the function:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *p;
    char *q;
    q = p;       // Pointless statment because q is overwritten                                                   
    q = "hello"; // right here                                                                                   
    puts(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C is (outside the preprocessor, which is its own horrible beast), strictly pass-by-value.

Thus, when one says "passing a variable" in reality one nearly always means "passing *the value of* a variable". Yes, sloppy speaking (and/or thinking) sinks projects.
In the rare cases "passing a variable" actually *means* what it *says*, that is emulated by "passing *the address of* a variable". Because it is so comparatively rare and the simpler phrase has been usurped, be explicit if that's what you mean.

Naturally, changing a copy has no effect on the source at all, nor does a copy reflect changes to the source after the fact.

Now you know why `p` in `main()` is still indeterminate after the call to `store2()`, and why treating it as (a pointer to) a string causes [Undefined Behavior](/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).